# How to find xpath for first searched product

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu

How to find XPath for the first searched element on given page
https://www.amazon.com/b/?encoding=UTF8&node=2346727011&bbn=7141123011&ref_=Oct_d_odnav_1040660&pd_rd_w=WJf7p&pf_rd_p=72459b27-e231-4837-b61c-b057ff0c50ac&pf_rd_r=YMKJ7M0AMXW5GER3MMRQ&pd_rd_r=eba15a0a-f59c-4dfd-a693-7c2f7f3416cf&pd_rd_wg=LRrkE

I tried the below XPath..on html page its showing the element but when putting on selenium code it's showing the error `invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression`

```
//div[@id='CardInstance1wPgwM8pHmoJmdnyjYOeWg']//child::div[2]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small s-title-instructions-style']//span
```

Please help me to find xpath for first searched product.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use

```
//li[starts-with(@class,'octopus-pc-item')]
```

this does have 26 entries and is not unique in HTML, however, `findElement` will return the first matching node.

Furthermore, you can do indexing like below

```
(//li[starts-with(@class,'octopus-pc-item')])[1]
```

and `[2]` for the second product and so on... for other products

Perform click like below

1. Using `ExplicitWaits`

   ```
   wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[starts-with(@class,'octopus-pc-item')]"))).click();
   ```
2. Using `findElement`

   ```
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[starts-with(@class,'octopus-pc-item')])[1]")).click();
   ```

Comment: Hi this is working         //li[starts-with(@class,'octopus-pc-item')][1]. Thankyou so much